# F# how to write an empty statement

Tags: f#, unit-type

How can I write a no-op statement in F#?

Specifically, how can I improve the second clause of the following match statement:

```
match list with
    | [] -> printfn "Empty!"
    | _ -> ignore 0
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use unit for empty side effect:

```
match list with
  | [] -> printfn "Empty!"
  | _ -> ()
```

Comment: Where "()" is the value of type "unit", and "unit" is the return type of "printfn", somewhat akin to "void".

Comment: Can I use it for Empty While loop ?

Comment: Absolutely, since the body of a while loop must be an expression of type `unit`.

Answer (score 18):

The answer from *Stringer* is, of course, correct. I thought it may be useful to clarify how this works, because "()" insn't really an empty statement or empty side effect...

In F#, *every valid piece of code is an expression*. Constructs like `let` and `match` consist of some keywords, patterns and several sub-expressions. The F# grammar for `let` and `match` looks like this:

```
<expr> ::= let <pattern> = <expr>
           <expr>
       ::= match <expr> with
           | <pat> -> <expr>
```

This means that the body of `let` or the body of clause of `match` must be some expression. It can be some function call such as `ignore 0` or it can be some value - in your case it must be some expression of type `unit`, because `printfn ".."` is also of type `unit`.

The `unit` type is a type that has only one value, which is written as `()` (and it also means empty tuple with no elements). This is, indeed, somewhat similar to `void` in C# with the exception that `void` doesn't have *any* values.

BTW: The following code may look like a sequence of statements, but it is also an expression:

```
printf "Hello "
printf "world"
```

The F# compiler implicitly adds `;` between the two lines and `;` is a sequencing operator, which has the following structure: `<expr>; <expr>`. It requires that the first expression returns `unit` and returns the result of the second expression.

This is a bit surprising when you're coming from C# background, but it makes the langauge surprisingly elegant and consise. It doesn't limit you in any way - you can for example write:

```
if (a < 10 && (printfn "demo"; true)) then // ...
```

(This example isn't really useful - just a demonstration of the flexibility)