# Empty with/finally block in try statement

Tags: f#

I want to `try` something:

```
try
    0/0
```

and I don't care if it fails, raising an `Exception`. But leaving a `with` or `finally` block empty makes the file unparsable.

This works, but it's not fun to write.

```
finally
    null |> ignore
```

How to leave the `with`/`finally` blocks (as) empty (as possible)?

Comment: Try `()`, [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704267/f-how-to-write-an-empty-statement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every expression must have a result, and `try ... with` is no exception. The `try` part is evaluated and a result is obtained. But if the `try` part fails, the result of the `with` part is substituted instead.

If your `try` part is `0/0`, then the result type of it is `int`. Therefore, in order for the types to match, the result of your `with` part should also be `int`. Think about what the result of the whole expression should be when the `try` part fails, and stick it in there:

```
let foo = 
    try 0/0
    with _ -> 42
```

Since you're saying that `null |> ignore` works, I must conclude that your `try` part is not in fact `0/0`. The `ignore` function returns `()` (a value of type `unit`), so if that works for you in the `with` part, then your `try` part must be also returning `unit`. If that is the case, you can use `()` as the `with` part instead of `null |> ignore`.

```
let foo =
    try printfn "Let's pretend that printfn may fail"
    with _ -> ()
```

For reference, this is (roughly) how `ignore` is defined:

```
let ignore x = ()
```